# How to add a date in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to add or sub a date?

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, -1, '2017-08-25') AS DATEADD
```

**ERROR:**

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 98 
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Tag our question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3):

Your query works fine in SQL Server (see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ac80f2f3c9302e0b91446b72b3bb3dc1)).

You may have arcane internationalization settings that do not treat `'2015-08-25'` as YYYY-MM-DD.

There are two choices.  You can drop the hyphens:

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, -1, '20170825') AS DATEADD
```

SQL Server always treats date strings with eight digits as a date in the format YYYYMMDD.

Or do an explicit conversion:

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, -1, CONVERT(DATE, '2017-08-25', 120)) AS DATEADD
```

Comment: Can you explain me what is the "120" on the second query?

Comment: 120 is date time conversion type. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp

Comment: @KetanKotak, casting the literal as date will also interpret the literal as an ISO 8601 date format regardless of session settings: `SELECT DATEADD(month, -1, CAST('2017-08-25' AS date)) AS DATEADD`

Comment: @Mikev . . . `120` is a conversion format parameter explained in the documentation:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.

Answer (score 0):

1- If you have date datatype of your column then you can directly do add or sub on date like below

```
select datecol -1 as sub_op , datecol+1 as sub_op2 from your_table
```

2- If you want to convert string to date in oracle you can use to_date function as below

```
select to_date('28-May-2019','DD-MM-YYYY') from dual;
```

or if mysql

```
STR_TO_DATE('2013-02-11', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    enter code here

SELECT convert (varchar(15),DATEADD(day, 1, '2017/08/25'),103) AS DateAdd;  -- dd/MM/YYYY only 



SELECT convert (varchar(15),DATEADD(DAY, -1, '2017/08/25'),103) AS DateAdd; -- dd/MM/YYYY

1.year, yyyy, yy = Year
2.quarter, qq, q = Quarter
3.month, mm, m = month
4.dayofyear = Day of the year
5.day, dy, y = Day
6.week, ww, wk = Week
7.weekday, dw, w = Weekday
8.hour, hh = hour
9.minute, mi, n = Minute
10.second, ss, s = Second
11.millisecond, ms = Millisecond
```